# Algorithm for determine category for scraped content

Tags: algorithm

i'm scraping several websites with recipes and i really wan't to try an create some kind of algorithm that divide recipes into different categories. i guess can't be completely perfect, but what is best practice. Do i start by for instance creating static categories in a database and then create another table with static keywords which has a foreign key to the categories and then check the scraped text if it contains one of the keywords, or what is the right approach?

Comment: The right approach is different for each of the different versions of the problem you're describing. Can you elaborate more on what the input looks like, and what the desired output should look like. I.e. how many categories (or variable), what does a recipe look like, can a recipe belong to more than 1 category, etc. Chances are you do not know the answers to these questions yet, if so, you have to define your problem first in order to find a solution to it.

Comment: Lets say that i have something like Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, salad, bread, snacks, drinking and dessert. a recipe consist of a title, guidance and ingredients. I'm not to sure whether a recipe should be able to go into several categories. That depends on whether what is easiest. I wan't to start out with an easy starting point, which i'm able to develop further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for in my opinion is a classification algorithm that defines classes (read categories) through the means of predefined recipes or properties of recipes.

A way you could implement this is create a large dictionary of words that live in the guidances, recipes and even titles of all recipes. Then you define your static amount of categories (this approach does not work with a variable number of categories) and define how much every word in your dictionary would predict a recipe containing that word to belong to that category.

You can do this by lets say for a 100 recipes manually tell the algorithm in which category they belong so that your algorithm will create the weights of the words that these recipes have (e.g. a desert recipe containing the word "fruit" will increase a future recipe containing the the word "fruit"'s chances of being categorized as a desert recipe.

Then when your algorithm has been calibrated for these 100 recipes (clearly the number 100 could be larger or smaller, though larger is usually better) you can test your algorithm by inserting known recipes into the algorithm and see how often the algorithm gets it right. You can upgrade your algorithm by letting it learn from his results, but as long as you're satisfied with the accuracy of your algorithm, you should be fine.

Comment: Do you have any example of how a database structure could look like in this case or a link to similar cases?

Comment: Well you need a set of categories you defined, and a (large) set of words you selected. Each word needs to be able to hold a reference to each category, so either make 1 table for categories, 1 for words and 1 table that chains both together with a value of how much a word belongs to a category, *or* make 1 big table that has a column for each category, so that a row defines a word, storing it's belonginess to each category in the columns. I would go for the first option myself as a lot of words will have 0 for its weight, meaning you can reduce the amount of data by truncating those records.

Answer (score 0):

First define what you mean by "categories". Than think about how to detect them e.g.

- keywords in the text
- ingredients.

If you are not yet sure , try some combinations and have a look at the results. You can also throw AI algorithms on it e.g. train a neuronal network to detect the category.

Comment: Lets say that i have something like Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner, salad, bread, snacks, drinking and dessert. a recipe consist of a title, guidance and ingredients. I'm not to sure whether a recipe should be able to go into several categories. That depends on whether what is easiest. I wan't to start out with an easy starting point, which i'm able to develop further.

Comment: @Peter Pik: I think some ingredients are unusual for e.g. Breakfast like potatoes or spinach.